# Angularjs translation using custom filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is an old project upgraded from angularjs 1.2 to 1.6 that uses constant, service and filter to translation.
Strings was translated ok in all page scope, but after upgrading doesn't work. An example about how code is:

app.js

```
.constant("config", {
    "translations": {
      'es': {
        'Default string': 'String por defecto',
      }
    }
});
```

service.js

```
return function(text) {
  var lang = $rootScope.lang;
  var langExists = typeof config.translations[lang] !== 'undefined';
  if (lang && langExists && config.translations[lang][text]) {
    return config.translations[lang][text];
  }
  return text;
};
```

filter.js

```
return function(text) {
  return translateService(text);
};
```

index.html

```
        <div class="dropdown pull-right">
          <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
        {{ 'Default string' | translate }}   <span class="caret"></span></button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="cursor:pointer;">
            <li><a ng-href="#" ng-click="header.changeLanguage('es')">es</a></li>
            <li><a ng-href="#" ng-click="header.changeLanguage('en')">en</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

controller.js

```
var vm = this;

  vm.language = 'Select language';

  vm.changeLanguage = function(lang) {
    $rootScope.lang = lang;
  };
```

Actually in this point, data is retrieved using $resource.

The point and problem is that when a user click change language, all strings using {{ 'String' | translate }} must be translated in all scopes. And before upgrade, this works.

What is blowing my mind is that I can not understand why worked in past because filters are not called again and scopes are not connected throw a service...
How can "refresh" strings in all controllers and scopes in app translated using a custom filter?

Comment: Here you are a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/The_Bear/Ln42Lh7j/11/) with your problem. Post it in the question. I'd tried to resolve, but I don't know why it doesn't work. Please update the fiddle and tell me if I'm doing something wrong. Good luck

Comment: Thank you very much! Updated here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ln42Lh7j/15/ but still not working filter translation refresh when config changed...

Comment: Ok, solved. From Angular 1.3, content that uses filter only "refresh" once, it is not "state aware" because as literal string never changes...It is necsessary to add filter.$stateful = true; in filter declaration.

Comment: Woow, to difficult to find the solution. Please, update the jsFiddle if you can so I could post an answer or post it yourself... :)

Comment: Yes, a nightmare! updated http://jsfiddle.net/Ln42Lh7j/17/ Thank you!